# Is the word 'Internet' a global word?

Tags: international

Is the word 'internet' regarded as a global word, meaning that it's been borrowed as-is into every language?

And if so, is it the first word to be used globally in every language?

Edit: looking at the response it seems I need to define what I mean by *global* *word*. I mean **spoken word** written phonetically, not written specifically in the Roman alphabet.

Comment: Are you asking whether the word "Internet" is used as-is in every language? Or whether all other languages merely transliterate it? It doesn't take long with Google Translate to prove that it's also spelled "Internet" in French and Spanish, but clearly not in Arabic or Mandarin. But, listening to the pronunciations of the Arabic and Mandarin words, they are clearly *meant* to sound like the English word "Internet." Is that what you are asking?

Comment: Is it the first word to do what, exactly? Elucidate.

Comment: Hmmm...this is actually a much better question than I was originally giving it credit for (no offense). I just played around with a whole host of Google Translate conversions, and each translation (that I tried, and that had audio) sounded like "Internet" (or as close to that set of phonemes as is possible in the target language). I don't know that we'll be able to determine if this is the *first* such word, but it's a tantalizing theory.

Comment: @Nonnal: It's "Interrete" in Latin, according to Wikipedia.

Comment: I don't think asking about the word for "Internet" in other languages has much to do with the English language in particular. What do you mean by asking if it is a global English word? Do you want to know if it is used across the globe by English speakers?

Comment: @sumelic: No I mean is it classed as an english word if it's used globally? Or is it a new kind of global language?

Answer (score 1):

According to the google translate, the hypothesis for *internet* fails for Chinese.  I can give you an existence proof for a "global word," but it may be unsatisfying since it's restricted to a particular argot, the language of air traffic control, which is conducted entirely in English.  It doesn't matter if it's an Air France flight flown by a German pilot flying into to a Philippines airport with a Spanish-speaking controller, all conversations between plane and tower will be in English.

The word *heavy* is a term of art in ATC referring to large aircraft -- those weighing over 300K pounds at takeoff.  (That's most wide-bodied jets, including Boeing 7X7's, for X greater than 6.)  When the tower says "Air France 123 **heavy**" everybody on the ground and in the air understands "heavy" to mean that Air France flight #123 is a plane of a certain size.  And nobody says *gros*, *schwere*, or *pesado*.

Comment: But perhaps it's worth noting that the pronunciation of the three characters that make up the Chinese word for Internet (*Yīntèwǎng*) clearly point to it as a transliteration. So if you lump transliterations as "close enough" to the original word, the hypothesis might still hold.